# How to keep position of image fixed while scrolling?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a web site which is made in WordPress. All of the content on my pages is wrapped in a div. What I would like to do now is add banners on both sides of the content and keep them fixed while scrolling.


So, the top of the banners should be aligned with the top.

The right side of the left banner should be right next to the left side of the main content.

The left side of the right banner should be right next to the left side of the main content.


Hence, I would get all elements from left to right: left banner -> content -> right banner. All aligned at the top. And when I scroll the page, only the content will scroll and not the banners.
It's important that the banners are anchored to the sides of the content, so if the width of the browser shrinks then parts of the banners are going out of screen instead of the banners going over the main content.

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Comment: It depends only on your structure, if the ads are separate from the content, you can use ` position:fixed;` in your div définition. Update your question with your structure will help.

Comment: Maybe just position fixed won't work, you may need JS to get what you want based on the last paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

you can use css. Position fixed actually. Here a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmb8qw7m/)
ex:

```
 .banner {
      position:fixed;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: mediumaquamarine;
      top: 40px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix them with

```
position:fixed;
```

For aligning them on top you have to work with margin and float I guess.
As example left banner:

```
float:left;
```

Now you can easily work with margins to position them right.
I hope that's what you meant ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming banners have got a `class="banner banner-right"` or `class="banner banner-left"` go with

```
.banner {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0; /* or the distance from top page edge */
   max-height: 100%;
}
.banner-right { right: 0; } /* or the distance from right page edge */
.banner-left { left: 0; } /* or the distance from left page edge */
```

and the banners will stick in the same position even if you scroll the page!
The `max-height` is there to prevent banners from being longer than the window itself, thus hiding content;

you might want to add `overflow: auto;` if the banner content gets too long

Another solution wold be to set

```
 html, body { height: 100%; }
.content { max-height: 100%; overflow: auto; }
```

making the content element with a scrollbar, and leaving the banners in the same place

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`position: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) like:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
```